# Reading A mix of Int and Float values from a .txt file in C

Tags: c

I have this text file here:

```
6 
81.00 
1 
27 
2004 
8 
7.00 
1 
2 
2009 
14 
97.00 
4 
4 
2001 
10 
38.00 
5 
17 
2006
```

and I am trying to read all of these values into an array.  Here is the bit of code that I have come up with:

```
int a[20], i, m;
FILE *fn;
fn = fopen("test.txt", "r");
m = 0;
i = 0;
while(!feof(fn)){
    for(i = 0; i < 20 ;i+=1){
        fscanf(fn, "%d", &a[i]);
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    m += 1;
}
```

This code correctly reads the first value of the text file because it is an integer but then incorrectly reads the rest of the values and I am assuming it's because of the fact that the second value in the text file is a float.  I'm not sure if this is possible in C but if it is, I'm pretty sure that reading the integer lines separately from the float lines would work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do not you read them as float or doubles ?,well read the "float" and "int" type correctly.

Comment: [while(!feof(fp)) is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)

Comment: There is a clear pattern to your data: int - float - int - int - int. Last int looks like it represents a year.

Comment: Yes I am aware that there is a pattern in the data.  I actually produced the data in the same program and the question that I was given asks for the data to be produced in that way.

Comment: Start with the data structure.  What data structure do you want to end up with once the file is read?  An array of structs?  An array of floats?  An array of ints?

Comment: Why doesn't code check the return value of `fscanf()`?

Comment: or don't use `fscanf`, search `fgets vs fscanf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your input file, you have an `int`, then `double` (or `float`) and 3-more `int` values before the input pattern repeats. You match your read to your input. Here if you read and `int`, a `double`, and 3-more `int` values in a loop, you can properly read the data in the file and you can store, or use, the `int`, `double` and `int, int, int` however you like.

The key is to match your read loop to your input.

There is nothing to say you can't loop reading one value at a time until `EOF` keeping a counter (e.g. with `int n = 0;`) and then use some *whacky logic* like

```
if (n) { 
    if (n == 1)      /* read double; n++ */ 
    else if (n == 4) /* read int; n = 0; */ 
) else               /* read int, n++ */`
```

But that would certainly be a weird way to approach the problem. Or you can just make use of the fact that numeric *format specifiers* for `scanf` will skip leading whitespace (newlines being whitespace) and just read all values in a single loop.

Here is a simple example of a less whacky way to do it. You can then choose whatever value you need in an array and fill the array accordingly, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int id, mo, day, year;  /* 4-int values   */
    double val;             /* 1-double value */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read an int, double, int, int, int, use as required */
    while (fscanf (fp, "%d %lf %d %d %d", &id, &val, &mo, &day, &year) == 5)
        printf (" %02d/%02d/%04d  %2d  %5.2f\n", mo, day, year, id, val);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** generally a better approach is to use `fgets` and then `sscanf` to parse the values from a buffer (which allows independent validation of the read and parse). However, when intentionally eating line ends as whitespace, `fscanf` alone can provide an advantage (one of the only circumstances where that is true).

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat prodid.txt
6
81.00
1
27
2004
8
7.00
1
2
2009
14
97.00
4
4
2001
10
38.00
5
17
2006
```

**Example Use/Output**

The following is just an example of using the values read each trip through the loop:

```
$ ./bin/rdprod <prodid.txt
 01/27/2004   6  81.00
 01/02/2009   8   7.00
 04/04/2001  14  97.00
 05/17/2006  10  38.00
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.